# jobb tool IO exception FAT full

Tags: android, google-play

Although there was some questions related to this issue and even open issue in Google bug tracker from year 2013, but i don't see any solution.
according to Android docs:

> Each time you upload an APK using the Google Play Console, you have the option to add one or two expansion files to the APK. Each file can be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose

My assets size on disk in only 260 MB (the folder that should be converted to OBB).

And i have exception:

> Slop: 58403307   Directory Overhead: 2168256
>   java.io.IOException: FAT Full (33689, 33690)

Everything worked well for years until now, we wanted to update the assets content with additional +30 MB, and currently we stuck.

Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36968595